# How do I change my editor font size in Matlab R2014b?

Tags: matlab

I've recently installed Matlab R2014b and I don't seem to manage changing the editor's font size.
Can you give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's in Preferences > Matlab > Fonts

[image]

Also, you might want to see [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/09/01/choose-a-good-font-your-eyes-will-thank-you/) post.